# Leicester City FC in the seasons 2015/2016 and 2014/2015

Tags: football, english-premier-league

So, in this season, the season 2015/2016, the English Premier League was won by Leicester.

The interesting thing is that in the season before, the season 2014/2015, Leicester ended the season in fourteenth place and if they had only 7 points fewer, would have been relegated to the second (Championship) league.

So, it is kind of a football/soccer miracle that they won the English Premier League.

> I would like to know if there are any similar examples of football/soccer clubs that were at some season close to the relegation zone and then won the title in the next season?

Edit: I would like to note here that an examples from other leagues other than English Premier League are welcomed, and as I was requested to objectively  define what it means to be "close to relegation zone", let us take for the purpose of the question only teams who were 7 or less points from the relegation zone in one season and then won the title in the next season.

Comment: In England now, as @qwertylpc said in his answer, but Nottingham Forest promoted and went on to win the Division One in their first season.

Comment: Can you please define "close to relagation" in a objective way?

Answer (score 8):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYJ7f.png)I remember reading [this in the past](http://harvardsportsanalysis.org/2015/12/why-leicester-city-shouldnt-be-atop-the-table-a-historical-look-at-parity-in-the-epl/).  Basically scroll down to the 3rd to last graph and the author is claiming that no team has won the EPL from below 3rd the year before.  It also looks like Chelsea set a new record for futility in that they fell the furthest of any EPL champ

Edit:

Here is the graph I was talking about:
[image: Link I was talking about]

Comment: Can you quote the statement(s) you're referring to? Links can die, or be edited. Additional references to corroborate are also a good idea.

Comment: @Nij I will add that in case of link rot, there are also [snapshots in Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://harvardsportsanalysis.org/2015/12/why-leicester-city-shouldnt-be-atop-the-table-a-historical-look-at-parity-in-the-epl/). Still, I agree that answers on this site should be posted in the way that they can be read and understood standalone, without need of going to other sites.